# How to design an invite feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

hello i am trying to implement a feature in my facebook application that would give 100 point to someone who would send 10 invitations. however i want a limit that feature for each user to use it only 10 times a day.
how should i design my feature to do what i want

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read up on how invites work on Facebook.

1. Invites are not allowed to be incentivized, which what you are doing.
2. Facebook imposes limits on your app on how many invites can be sent by each person each day. The limit depends on how well people respond to the invites. The default is between 12 and 20, and can go as low as 8.
3. Facebook enforces the limits it imposes automatically.

On the plus side, you should be tracking invites. The invite API responds with the IDs of the friends who the invite was sent to. You should use that information to not display those users on the next invite so the same user doesn't get multiple invites.